# Why words are the basic building blocks of language?

Tags: semantics, computational-linguistics, words

I'm asking this both in the sense that for me (as a human) words seem to be the fundamental building blocks of language, and from the perspective of NLP applications, where word-vectors and word-embeddings are probably the most popular/wide-spread representations. So maybe it's not just me, and most people would consider words to be the basic unit.

I have a hunch it's got something to do with the balance between complexity and expressivity. E.g., there are only 26 letters in the English alphabet, so the complexity is quite low, but there's not much meaning carried by letters alone. In comparison, there are about 170,000 words in the English language (according to some dictionary) - though most people probably only use 20-40,000 of them. So, the complexity is bigger, but also the expressivity. There are probably countless different sentences that exist or can exist in English, and so while the expressivity is higher, so is the complexity.

So, I would hypothesize that words are a sort of an optimal balance point.

Was there any research done on this? Any more prominent language people expressing their beliefs on the matter?

Comment: Words _aren’t_ necessarily the ‘basic’ building blocks of language, if such a thing can even be said to exist. Phonemes are at least a basic building block, and I would say morphemes are a more useful basic building block than words. Very simplistically, you use phonemes to build morphemes, morphemes to build words, and words to build sentences – why should any one of those levels be more ‘basic’ to language than the others? (Letters are not involved at all; they’re only used for transforming language into a different medium, but they’re irrelevant to actual language production.)

Comment: Words are the basic block that still convey some meaning. That is why when you go to a foreign country you don't point on and object and ask for its phoneme, you ask for the word.

Comment: Morphemes also convey meaning – that’s their defining property. ‘Words’ (notoriously ill-defined) can convey _too much_ meaning. In agglutinative and especially polysynthetic languages, there can be a virtually unlimited number of words, because a single word can incorporate so much more than we’re used to in English. For example, Yupik _tuntussuqatarniksaitengqiggtuq_ is a single word meaning, “(s)he had not yet said again that (s)he was going to hunt reindeer” – would you say that’s a ‘basic’ building block? It consists of seven morphemes, which would be more useful building blocks.

Comment: Even in English, is it more useful as a building block to know precisely what _antidisestablishmentarianism_ means as a whole word, or to know individually what _anti-_, _dis-_, _establish_, _-ment_, _-ary_, _-an_ and _-ism_ mean as morphemes and then build up the combined meaning of the full word yourself? Isn’t that what building blocks are all about?

Comment: Oh, and the alphabet and English spelling has nothing to do with language or meaning. That's just our peculiar way of writing Modern English as if it were Middle English. Sounds are what people use in language, and words are built of sounds.

Comment: How about dealing with functions like nouns and verbs? You got the thing and what you do to it. There is basically a infinite variety of utterances that can be produced in English using its phonemes. And by the way, counting all the science etc. English has more words than any other language in history, People argue about it but it's at least +/- 600,000, which makes me happy. Who could know all that in one lifetime?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, there are compound words. But even native speakers sometimes never stop to think that a word is actually a compound, and when they do they have a moment of insight. In any case, I don't see the existence of compound words as a proof that words are not the basic building blocks. At most it shows that the border is not very clear. You seem to be against it, and I don't think I can convince you. So, let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @jlawler "oh, and" implies you said something before...? The representations with letters or with sounds is irrelevant. Syllables don't convey enough meaning by themselves.

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat Neither of the two words I gave as examples is a compound.

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat No, it's in reference to something you said. And what evidence is there that syllables don't convey enough meaning by themselves? They do very well in Vietnamese, for instance. And an immense amount of English is monosyllablic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few conceptual and terminological problems with your assumption, which are fully encouraged by linguists who use certain words interchangeably, at least some of the time.
The first distinction that needs to be made is between "language" and "grammar". Let's say that "language" is the observable stuff that people create – a corpus – and "grammar" is a set of principles that describe (create, etc) that corpus (wholely or partially). The concept of a "building block" only makes sense from the perspective of grammar. If language is just a corpus, there is no "building".

From the perspective of the grammar, there are two very different notions of "basic building block". One is, what are the most basic objects required to define the representations and computations of a language or of human languages. The other is, what is the epistemological hierarchy required to discover a grammar. That is the only sense in which words might be "basic building blocks": they are the most-accessible bits from the language corpus from which one can induce a grammar.

The corpus that constitutes a "language" will contain innumerable strings, some of which are single words and some of which are combinations of words. Since the corpus is just the collection of outputs, it will also include things that are not strictly the result of a grammar, so it may include a sub-part of a word.

Typically when a linguist sets out to discover the grammar of a language, they ask for names of specific objects like dog, chicken, stick, water and so on. The speaker usually figures out that this is a request for a particular word. As you progress in your analysis, you end up encountering things that are two or more words, but you always try to understand what the combination is by understanding the parts that go into the combination.

On the other hand, from the perspective of "what is the most basic concept or two" necessary to talk about grammar, that is an extremely contentious topic. As a starter, I suggest that grammar is about an "informational network", which can be talked about as "typed nodes and their relations". But this is very broad: it is more about cognition and not specifically about grammar.

In fact, in light of the extant disparities between semantics, syntax, morphology, phonology and phonetics, it is becoming increasingly likely that there is no single "basic building block of grammar".

Comment: It thought it's called "linguistics" not "grammistics".